# RtlStringCbCopyW Does copy only first char of the string why?

Tags: unicode-string

I have problem in copying string from on type to another. code which have problem I have given below.

```
DbgPrint("Value of ProcessName =%wZ \n",&ProcessName);
//The Type of ProcessName is UNICODE_STRING

RtlStringCbCopyW(myBuffer,((MAX_PATH+90)*sizeof(WCHAR)),ProcessName.Buffer);
//try to copy from ProcessName.Buffer to myBuffer

DbgPrint("Value of MyBuffer =%s \n",MyBuffer);
//The Type of MyBuffer is Array of WCHAR

DbgPrint("Value of ProcessName.Buffer =%s \n",ProcessName.Buffer);
```

Output:-

```
Value of ProcesssName =\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\explorer.exe
Value of MyBuffer =\
Value of ProcesssName.Buffer =\
```

why it is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem here in invalid format `%s` in `DbgPrint` - you need use `%S` instead. strings in your case copied correct, you only incorrect displayed it - `%s` assumed ansi string at stop after first `\0` byte (in first WCHAR symbol). however in general case use [`RtlStringCbCopyW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562805(v=vs.85).aspx) is error - because [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564879(v=vs.85).aspx) can be not null-terminated and can containing null characters. need use [`RtlCopyUnicodeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561817(v=vs.85).aspx). and finally this not related to `driver` `minifilter` and `kernel-mode` only to `unicode-string`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. its now working. actually I m doing kernel mode programming on minifilter driver that's why I have added these tags..

Comment: I have one more question that if I want to extract \Windows\explorer.exe from \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\explorer.exe what I have to do for this?

Comment: @KashifMeo- what you mean under "extract" ?? if you want got FS path only from  full nt-path - can open file and then query it `FileNameInformation`

Comment: means I want this substring Windows\explorer.exe from this string \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\explorer.exe. actually i have to compare two strings that's why i want this sub string

Comment: Other string comes from user mode. in the form Windows\explorer.exe

Comment: @KashifMeo - can not say without understanding context. this is separate question